# Synchronizing two tables, best practice

Tags: t-sql, triggers, synchronization

I need to synchronize two tables across databases, whenever either one changes, on either update, delete or insert. The tables are NOT identical.

So far the easiest and best solution i have been able to find is adding SQL triggers.

Which i slowly started adding, and seems to be working fine. But before i continue finishing it, I want to be sure that this is a good idea? And in general good practice.

If not, what a better option for this scenario?

Thank you in advance

Regards 
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers will work, but there are quite a few different options available to consider.

Are all data modifications to these tables done through stored procedures? If so, consider putting the logic in the stored procedures instead of in a trigger.

Do the updates have to be real-time? If not, consider a job that regularly synchronizes the tables instead of a trigger. This probably gets tricky with deletes, though. Not impossible, just tricky.

We had one situation where the tables were very similar, but had slightly different column names or orders. In that case, we created a view to the original table that let the application use the view instead of the second copy of the table. We were also able to use a Synonym one time to point to the original table, but that requires that the table structures be the same.

Generally speaking, a lot of people try to avoid unnecessary triggers as they're just too easy to miss when doing other work in the database. That doesn't make them bad, but can lead to interesting times when trying to troubleshoot problems.

In your scenario, I'd probably briefly explore other options before continuing with the triggers. Just watch out for cascading trigger effects where your one update results in the second table updating, passing the update back to the first table, then the second, etc. You can guard for this a little with nesting levels. Otherwise you run the risk of hitting that maximum recursion level and throwing errors.